# Appium + iOS automation : Error "Could not write domain com.apple.keyboard.preferences; exiting"

Tags: automated-testing, python, mobile-automation, ios

Team,
Everything was working and suddenly I observed all the tests started failing :( with following error :

> **Could not write domain com.apple.keyboard.preferences; exiting**

What all I have tried :

1. First and foremost I checked Network
2. Then verified other system components such as Simulator, Appium server

They are set & working as expected. By any chance you have work around for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution :

- I found this issue is **intermittent**.

> **sh "xcrun simctl shutdown $(xcrun simctl list devices | grep -m 1 'iPhone 12 Pro' |grep -E -o -i '([0-9a-f]{8}-([0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12})')"**

- I have added above snippet under post { } in jenkins pipeline.
- Basically **idea is to shutdown** the booted simulator always after execution **irrespective** of outcome i.e. **pass or fail**
- Thereafter I have not observe this issue again till date.

Happy Testing :)